# Children of ViewPager

Tags: java, android, android-viewpager

When I'm trying to get child's X of ViewPager I always get strange numbers, not correct ones.

```
@Override
        public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset,
                int positionOffsetPixels) {
            int realPosition = position;

            for (int i =0 ; i < getChildCount(); i++) {
                Log.d("TAG", "X: " + getChildAt(i).getX());
            }
```

I always get

```
D/TAG﹕ X: 41.0
D/TAG﹕ X: 1000.0
D/TAG﹕ X: 1960.0
D/TAG﹕ X: 2920.0
D/TAG﹕ X: 3880.0
```

How to get children which are currently visible on screen and how to get their real X's?

I want to set Alpha to child views depending on their position.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try **ViewPager.PageTransformer** for setting alpha
http://developer.android.com/training/animation/screen-slide.html

**Example:**

```
viewPager.setPageTransformer(true, new AlphaPageTransformer());
```

---

```
public class AlphaPageTransformer implements ViewPager.PageTransformer {
        private static final float MIN_SCALE = 0.75f;

        public void transformPage(View view, float position) {
            int pageWidth = view.getWidth();

            if (position < -1) { // [-Infinity,-1)
                // This page is way off-screen to the left.
                view.setAlpha(0);

            } else if (position <= 0) { // [-1,0]
                // Use the default slide transition when moving to the left page
                view.setAlpha(1);

            } else if (position <= 1) { // (0,1]
                // Fade the page out.
                view.setAlpha(1 - position);

            } else { // (1,+Infinity]
                // This page is way off-screen to the right.
                view.setAlpha(0);
            }
        }
    }
```